# how should I use "?" in Swift

Tags: swift

for example

```
if let name = jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as? String {
    println("name is \(name)")
} else {
    println("property was nil")
}
```

I have the follow question:

`jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as? String`   is the same as  `jsonDict["name"] as? AnyObject as? String`   yes or no?

`jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as? String`   is the same as  `jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as  String?`   yes or no?

I don't know the difference between as? String   and as String?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is huge difference between `as` and `as?`.

## `as`

the `as` downcasts the object and force-unwrap the result in every time, and it does not really care about the *real* type of the object or any fail-safe procedure. the responsibility is yours, therefore that can cause the following code crashes in runtime:

```
let jsonDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["name": 32]
if let downcasted: String = jsonDict["name"] as String?  { ... } else { ... }
```

the reason: it forcibly downcasts the `Int32` value to an *optional* `String` (=`String?`), and that cause a simple crash – if force-unwrapping fails, it will cause crash in every occasion in runtime.

> you can use this solution only when you are 100% certain the downcast won't fail.

therefore, if your dictionary looks like this:

```
let jsonDict: Dictionary<String, String?> = ["name": nil]        
if let downcasted: String = jsonDict["name"] as String? { ... } else { ... }
```

the *else-branch* will be executed, because the `String?` is `nil`, when you replace the `nil` with any string (e.g. `"My Name"`) in your dictionary, the *if-branch* will be executed in runtime as expected – if the *value* is any other type than *optional* `String`, a crash will happen as I highlighted above in every case when the value is not `nil`.

## `as?`

the `as?` optionally downcast the object, and if the downcasting procedure fails then it returns `nil`. that solution helps you to check the success of the donwcasting in runtime without suffering any crash:

```
let jsonDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["name": 32]
if let downcasted: String = jsonDict["name"] as? String  { ... } else { ... }
```

in that situation the *else-branch* will executed and your application can carry on, because the actual `Int32` value fails to be downcasted to `String` – if your *value* is a `String` (e.g. `"My Name"`) then the *if-branch* will be executed in runtime.

> you have to use this solution when you are not certain about which the actual object's type is in runtime and there is a chance the downcasting procedure could fail.

---

*NOTE: I would recommend to read the official docs about [type-casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) and [optional-chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) for better understanding the entire procedure.*

Comment: that is always challenging to figure out why someones downvotes without any clue, but I guess there was a good reason in their mind. God bless such geniuses. ;)

Answer (score 0):

jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as? String is the same as  jsonDict["name"] as? AnyObject as? String yes or no? - No, the latter makes no sense, you are trying to making a double cast from AnyObject to String. Furthermore, jsonDict["name"] would be enough for the compiler to recognize what type the return is, you shouldn't need any casting to a string.

jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as? String is the same as  jsonDict["name"] as AnyObject? as  String? yes or no?. Same as the first case, making a double cast makes little sense. Furthermore, the difference between as? and as is that as? will only execute in the case that the object can be successfully converted to the desired type, if this is not the case, the object will not be casted, therefore avoiding crashes.